# Условное объявление функции

Tags: javascript

В первой строчке не пойму зачем используется "+", подскажите пожалуйста.

Это пример и там ошибка, но не в + как я понимаю

```js
var age = +prompt("Сколько вам лет?", 20);

if (age >= 18) {
  function sayHi() {
    alert('Прошу вас!');
  }
} else {
  function sayHi() {
    alert('До 18 нельзя');
  }
}

sayHi();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Унарный плюс](https://learn.javascript.ru/operators) используется для приведения строки к числу

```js
console.log(typeof +'1')
```

Comment: А в коде как он работает, я просто только начать изучать js и вообще не понимаю, зачем он там

Comment: Вводить мы же будем в поле число, то есть как в коде: 20

Comment: @TerletskiyAlexander [prompt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt) возращает строку.

Answer (score 1):

Я понял и хочу объяснить новичкам очень простыми словами:
prompt возвращает строку и даже если мы пишем число, как в коде у меня указано 20, то prompt все равно вернет строку, пример:
(age === YOUR_NUMBER), именно поэтому мы и указываем унарный плюс(+).

Comment: Рекомендую вам еще до кучи изучить тему [приведения типов при сравнении](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B_%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F), полезно будет

Comment: Большое вам спасибо!